# iSCSI opcode[89], error(-65539)

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, iscsi, synology

I have error iSCSI target (Synology DS1813+) used as NAS:

> Jan 19 12:03:55 SRV1 kernel: [23311947.266497] iSCSI: iSCSI: EPIO[/volume1/@iSCSITrg/iSCSI_3_Extent_LUN-LUN1_000], opcode[89], error(-65539), pos(10578610176)

By wiki: [SCSI command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_command) this is command: "COMPARE AND WRITE".
But that mean this error? pos?

During this error on ESXi (iSCSI iniciator) I/O latency increased.

> Device "xxx" performance has deteriorated. I/O latency increased from average value of 29890 microseconds to 604191 
>   microseconds. warning

Long/Shot SMART test status is OK.

Answer (score 2):

"COMPARE AND WRITE" opcode usually means that your writing queue is continuously growing because of low disk write performance. The reason for such behavior may be a very highly loaded OS (Synology DSM) or faulty disk drive assuming that network connection from your ESX host to NAS is OK. First of all check CPU/RAM usage on your Synology box. Also check the S.M.A.R.T status and health of your disk drives. That should help you to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Thx to reply, Long/Shot SMART test status is OK.